# why am i getting an 1099: Syntax error? For inventory system

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Here is my code `var menu1:menu = new menu[];` it's for making an menu for my inventory system. I even  watched a video to to know if I'm doing it right and this is exactly what he did and he had no error and I'm using AS3 code.

Here is my error:

> error:Scene 1, Layer 'actions', Frame 1, Line 25, Column 27
>    Error #1099: `Syntax error` at code : `var menu1:menu = new menu[]`;

Problem code (added from comments) :

```
var slots:Array = []; 
var objects:Array = []; 
var inventory;

var menu1:menu = new menu[]; 
var menuOpen = (false); 
var beforeX; 
var beforeY; 

function init() 

{ stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyPressed); 

var b = 0; for(var i=0;i<16;i++); } 

{ 

var inv:invSlot = new invSlot(); 
slots.push(inv); 
slots[i].visible = false; 

if(i>=8) 
{ slots[i].x = 510-45 slots[i].y = 45.5*b+15 } 
else { slots[i].x = 510 slots[i].y = 45.5*1+15 }
```

Comment: Please add your code

Comment: code:var menu1:menu = new menu[];
error:Scene 1, Layer 'actions', Frame 1, Line 25, Column 27 1099

Comment: for some reason it took the code out of the question

Comment: when i watched the video this is what the video said to add to my code
var slots:Array = [];
var objects:Array = [];
var inventory;
var menu1:menu = new menu[];
var menuOpen = (false);
var beforeX;
var beforeY;
function init()
 {
  stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyPressed);
  var b = 0;
  for(var i=0;i<16;i++);
 }
 
 {
  var inv:invSlot = new invSlot();
  slots.push(inv);
  slots[i].visible = false;
  if(i>=8)
  {
   slots[i].x = 510-45
   slots[i].y = 45.5*b+15
  }
  
  else
  {
   slots[i].x = 510
   slots[i].y = 45.5*1+15
  }

Comment: slots[i].id = i;
  slots[i].used = false;
 }
 
 init();

Comment: rather than editing my question why not just answer the question i made it pretty clear

Comment: @RobertEldred people are downvoting your question because it makes no sense without code that causes error(s). Secondly, show me a link to the video (youtube?) cos I cannot believe a tutorial said _"write code like this"_. So many mistakes in there...

Comment: well i made sure people knew it was for a inventory system so what else am i supposed to say?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q_mwEj0KEjw&t=237s
also there is another guy who is way better but he hasnt posted in like 3 years so iv been tryign to find a good inventory system like pokemon or final fantasy, also do you know the code for picking up items and making them appear in your inventory?

Comment: You're getting syntax errors because your syntax is wrong. Learn the language first before trying to make a game. [AS3 Tutorials by Adobe](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning.html)

Answer (score 1):

> This is just an extended comment :

Some mistakes I've noticed...

**(1)**

If you intend to create a new instance of `menu` Class then `var menu1:menu = new menu[];` should be `var menu1:menu = new menu();`. Only use `[]` for arrayed (grouped) data *eg:* a list of items.

In `var inv:invSlot = new invSlot();` you did it fine for new instance of `invSlot();` Class.

**(2)**

A function begins `{` and ends with a closing `}` So in your code..

> `function init()`
>   ***function init() starts*** -->`{`  stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyPressed);
> var b = 0; for(var i=0;i<16;i++); `}` <-- ***function init() ends** here*.
>
> `{` <-- ***what does this extra achieve?*** Asking for an error soon? 
> Also later there is no closing `}` so yet another error will be given.
>
> var inv:invSlot = new invSlot(); 
>   slots.push(inv); 
>   slots[i].visible = false;

**(3)**

```
//# Is this a boolean (true/false) variable?
var menuOpen = (false); //what the...???

//# Are these supposed to be integers? Set like this, they will be null
var beforeX; var beforeY;
```

**(4)**

Pixel positions are in whole numbers (integers) only so you cannot use fractions like `y = 45.5`. Either set `.y` to be 45 or 46 pixels down.

.......

To cut explanation short, try something like this :

```
var slots:Array = []; 
var objects:Array = []; 

var inventory; //fix this!! should be format as... var NAME : TYPE = VALUE


var menu1:menu = new menu(); 
var menuOpen:Boolean = false; 
var beforeX:int = 0; 
var beforeY:int = 0; 

//keep it outside of any function XYZ for global access (now other functions can use it too)
var b:int = 0;

function init() : void
{ 
    b=0; //reset?
    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyPressed); 

    for(var i:int=0; i<16; i++)
    {
        var inv:invSlot = new invSlot(); 
        slots.push(inv); 
        slots[i].visible = false; 

        if (i >= 8) 
        { 
            slots[i].x = 510 - 45; //no fractions like 45.5
            slots[i].y = 45.5 * b+15;
        } 
        else 
        {   
            slots[i].x = 510;
            slots[i].y = 45 * 1+15;
        }

    }//end for loop

} //end function
```

Comment: ok and im just gonna use to menu for inventory shit i dont even care about the item shit yet but can you show me what it should look like all together with just the menu and inventory please and thanks :)

Comment: Did the above answer fix your posted `Error #1099: Syntax error`? If yes, then please mark as correct solution (click the grey `✔` tick). PS: I don't get what you mean by _"just the menu and inventory"_? From your shown code, what should they do?

Comment: when you hit a certain button (i) it opens your inventory with menu options

Comment: also it gives me an error about the type
error: Scene 1, Layer 'actions', Frame 1, Line 26, Column 16 1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: type.

Comment: Show the code of line 26. Is it like this pseudo-code `var NAME : TYPE = VALUE`? For `TYPE` you're supposed to use an AS3 **datatype**. Read [**`Datatypes Intro`**](http://codewithdesign.com/2010/02/08/introduction-to-as3-variable-types/) and read also : [**`ActionScript 3 Fundamentals : Data types`**](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/as3-fundamentals/data-types.html) and maybe also : [**`AS3 Variables`**](http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3variables/).